# Конструкция "обычно всегда"

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

Так говорила моя бабушка, и это всегда вызывало у меня улыбку. Вроде так говорить совершенно неправильно, но потом я стал ***часто*** слышать это выражение от других. Отчего же так распространена эта ошибка?

А ***вдруг*** это даже ***не ошибка?*** Тогда что это может означать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

С точки зрения формальной логики выражение "обычно всегда":

- либо является избыточным (тавтологией). Потому что "обычно" означает "в достаточно большой доле случаев", а "всегда" означает "в 100% случаев".
- либо является противоречием (нонсенсом). Иногда под "обычно" подразумевают "в достаточно большой, но не 100%-й, доле случаев", а "всегда" означает "в 100% случаев".

<sub>Но человеческая речь не всегда строится на формальной логике. Например, фраза "я — человек и мужчина" — с формальной точки зрения слово "человек" лишнее, потому что мужчина и так по-любому человек, и достаточно было бы сказать просто "я — мужчина", но провозглашающий эту фразу ("я — человек и мужчина"), по-видимому, вкладывает свои слова определённый подтекст: например, под словом "человек" он может иметь в виду соответствие какому-то одному образу (например, разум + гуманность + доброта + общечеловеческие слабости), а под словом "мужчина" — соответствие какому-то другому образу (например, сила + смелость + грубость), который не только не подразумевает в себе первый образ, но и вступает в определённое противоречие с ним.</sub>

Я не знаю, какой подтекст Ваша бабушка подразумевала под "обычно всегда". Я бы интерпретировал это выражение следующим образом.

<sub>В разных ситуациях у одного и того же человека включаются разные инстинкты и разное поведение. Например, когда Вы в обычной/нормальной ситуации, Вы чувствуете себя по-одному, когда сильно болеете, Вы чувствуете себя по-другому, когда Вы очень пьяны, Вы чувствуете себя по-третьему, когда за Вами по темному переулку гонится банда с ножами, Вы чувствуете себя по-четвёртому. Некоторые психологи считают, что такой вещи, как "личность", вообще не существует, и все мы просто наборы разных реакций на разные ситуации. У меня когда-то была девушка, которая любила говорить "это была не я" про ситуацию, в которой она вела себя неправильно / не по своим принципам.</sub>

Так вот, фразу "я **обычно всегда** плачу за проезд" я бы интерпретировал так: человек очень щепетильный, и он **всегда** платит за проезд — но это верно только в нормальной ситуации: если же за ним гонится банда с ножами, или он едет с острым приступом аппендицита, или иной форс-мажор, он может и не заплатить (поэтому **обычно**). С формальной точки зрения, он, конечно, не имеет права говорить "всегда", ведь если не 100%, то это уже не "всегда" — но с эмоциональной точки зрения ему нужно как-то подчеркнуть, что он очень щепетильный и никогда не позволяет себе не заплатить из-за лени, забытого дома кошелька и других *не форс-мажорных* вещей.

Comment: Спасибо, Саша, мне очень нравится Ваш ответ!!! Ответ Александра тоже, но Ваш особенно.

Answer (score 3):

В этом выражении явное противоречие между "не всегда" ("обычно") и "всегда". Что заставляет людей так говорить? Возможно, интуитивное стремление смягчить категоричность утверждения "всегда". На такую мысль наводят и другие способы выражения. В своё время было повальное увлечение присказкой "как бы", которая произносилась в бессознательной попытке снять с себя часть ответственности за сказанное. К счастью, это ушло, но сейчас угрожающие масштабы принимает произносимое с похожей целью выражение "в том числе" - вне должного контекста и без грамматической опоры местоимения "то" на что-либо ранее сказанное. Вероятно, за этим стоит неосознанное стремление на всякий случай "пометить" последующий довод как "просто пример", чтобы сказанное не поставили под сомнение и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! "Как бы", к сожалению, и сейчас часто слышу. А с "то", да, двоюродного брата 13-летнего никак не могу переучить, причём непонятно, от кого он это больше перенял — от сверстников или от тёти с дядей. Насчёт именно "в том числе" не помню, в нём или нет, но в чём-то подобном замечал ошибки, обращу теперь внимание.